# Customize Facebook Login Text

Tags: android, facebook

I want to show "Connect with Facebook".How i can change default text that show "Login with Facebook".

I am using android sdk version 4.18.0.Thanks.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connect_with_FB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Connect with Facebook"/>
```

**UPD**
with your code :

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Connect with Facebook"
    android:id="@+id/connect_with_FB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Comment: did you try this

Comment: Login with facebook is default text on facebook sdk 4.18.0.On 4.27.0,it changed to continue with facebook.I want to show connect with facebook.

Comment: @KurioTetsuya just change the text of com_facebook_login_text. updated the post. See the answer

Answer (score 0):

I using this way and it is work:

```
        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/fragment_login_btn_loginWithFacebook"
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            fb:login_text="Custom login text bla bla"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code and it you can change the text.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/connect_with_FB"
    facebook:com_facebook_login_text="addTextHere"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```